# Force View in an HStack to Expand Up to a Certain Size

Tags: swiftui

I have three views in an `HStack`. I’d like the center view to expand up to a certain size *even if its contents are too small for that size.* The left and right views should fill whatever space remains, down to a minimum width.

iPad:

[image: iPad View]

View B (grey) has expanded to its maximum size. Views A and C take up the remaining space.

iPhone:

[image: ideal view 2]

Views A and C (yellow and green) have shrunk down to a minimum width. View B (grey) fills the rest of the space.

This code doesn’t quite get there:

```
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text("A")
            .frame(minWidth: 20.0, maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.yellow)
        
        Text("B")
            .frame(minWidth: 0.0, maxWidth: 500.0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.secondary)
        
        Text("C")
            .frame(minWidth: 20.0, maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .background(Color.green)
    }
}
```

It produces this output:

[image: actual output]

In this case, view B’s content isn’t wide enough, so it doesn’t expand to fill its space.

To restate:

- B should get as wide as it can, up to a maximum (500 in this example)
- A and C should fill whatever space remains, down to a minimum size (20 in this example).

How do I force B to increase its width up to my maximum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give view B higher priority (default is 0). Tested with Xcode 12.

[image: demo]

```
Text("B")
    .frame(minWidth: 0.0, maxWidth: 500.0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
    .background(Color.secondary)
    .layoutPriority(1)           // << here !!
```